# Why isn't git reading the added file?

Tags: linux, git, difftool

I was reading an article that told me to add a file and place it in my *path*. Not knowing what the author meant by path, i simply put it in my root directory.

Trying to run 'git diffall', git says diffall is not a command, any ideas? Thanks in advance.

The article snippet for more information:

Write the following code to a file called `git-diffall` and place in your path (I put it in `>…/my-git-install-dir/cmd/` )

```
#!/bin/sh
git diff --name-only "$@" | while read filename; do
git difftool "$@" --no-prompt "$filename" &
done
```

And run it in git (with usual diff input parameters), for example:

> git diffall
>   git diffall HEAD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your 'path' is the collection of directories where the system looks for executables.  To see it, simply execute `echo $PATH` at the commandline.  Then put your script in one of those directories.